# Groovy groupBy on multiple properties and extracting only value

Tags: groovy

Having a list of elements:

```
List list =  [
    [category: 'A', name: 'a' value: 10],
    [category: 'A', name: 'b' value: 20],
    [category: 'B', name: 'a' value: 30],
    [category: 'B', name: 'c' value: 40],
    [category: 'B', name: 'd' value: 50],
]
```

I want to transform it into a nested map:

```
Map map = [
    A: [a: 10, b: 20],
    B: [a: 30, c: 40, d: 50],
]
```

The only solution I have come up with is to do something like this:

```
list.groupBy(
    { it.category }, { it.name }
).collectEntries { category, names ->
    [(category): names.collectEntries { name, values ->
        [(name): values.value[0]]
    }]
}
```

However, I will have to deal with more than 2 levels of nesting in the future, and this approach will be unfeasible.

Is there any neat way to obtain the proper result in Groovy that will be more flexible?

EDIT:

By more than 2 levels of nesting I mean converting structure like:

```
List list =  [
    [category: 'A', subcategory: 'I', group: 'x', name: 'a', value: 10],
    [category: 'A', subcategory: 'I', group: 'y', name: 'b', value: 20],
]
```

Into:

```
Map map = [
    A: [I: [
        x: [a: 10],
        y: [b: 20],
    ]],
]
```

By adding nesting (depth) it would require more nested `collectEntries` calls, which will become unreadable.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your data will look like with multiple levels of nesting?  It's not clear if you have nested values that need to go into top-level categories, or if your results need to be nested, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a neat solution to the problem by using `Map`'s `withDefault` method and recursive `Closure` calls:

```
Map map = { [:].withDefault { owner.call() } }.call()
list.each {
    map[it.category][it.name] = it.value
}
```

Or for the second case:

```
Map map = { [:].withDefault { owner.call() } }.call()
list.each {
    map[it.category][it.subcategory][it.group][it.name] = it.value
}
```